# How can I fix my rolling mean program in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to create a basic tensorflow program to compute and print the rolling mean of random variables to learn variable assignment etc.

I am not able to understand a few things

1. why do i need to supply the feed dict `session.run(current_sum_assign_op, feed_dict={current_random: num})`
2. why doesn't the values get added inside the loop, every time it only prints the random number generated divided by two.

code :

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

current_sum = tf.Variable(0, name='current_sum')
current_div = tf.Variable(1, name='div')

current_random = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[], name='current_random')

mean = tf.div(current_sum, current_div)

model = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as session:
    for i in range(100):
        num = np.random.random() * 100

        current_sum_assign_op = tf.assign(current_sum, value=current_sum + current_random)
        current_div_assign_op = tf.assign(current_div, value=current_div + 1)

        session.run(model)
        session.run(current_random, feed_dict={current_random: num})
        session.run(current_sum_assign_op, feed_dict={current_random: num})
        session.run(current_div_assign_op)
        session.run(mean)

        print('num =', num)
        print('mean = ')

        session.run(tf.Print(mean, [mean], 'Mean is'))
        session.run(tf.Print(current_div, [current_div], 'Div is'))
    session.run(model)
```

Can you help me understand what is going on and how I can fix it?

Comment: As indicated by the error, `'current_random'` is the name of the operation, and you need to refer to the tensor it outputs, so it should be `'current_random:0'`. You can also use the object `current_random` as `feed_dict` key.

Comment: I am still stuck with other errors though :(

Comment: `session.run(current_sum_assign_op)` also needs a `feed_dict` with `current_random`...

Comment: which results in the error : tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value current_sum

Comment: Uhm, you didn't run the variables initializer.

Comment: Isn't that's what tf.global_variables_initializer for?

Comment: Yes but that just creates the operation, you have to run it too with `session.run`. Take a look at the examples in the TensorFlow documentation and you will see this is typically one of the first steps after creating a session.

Comment: I really appreciate your help @jdehesa. I am still stuck at two questions, would you mind answering them in an answer so that I can also mark the question as answer? I've updated the original question to reflect it.